# Python Regular expression starting with abc and having @\defg for any path

Tags: python, python-re

I have a path = abc_0_1_1@/cdef/xxx/yyy/ddd/
I wanted to write regular expression pattern to validate string with abc and having @/cdef

I tried out

```
re.search(r"^[abc]@[/cdef]",path)
```

But not getting exactly .

Comment: `r"^[abc].+@[/cdef]"`

Comment: Yes this one worked out .Thanks